# Error Adding Rows on Entity Framework 5 with Sqlite "The relationship could not be changed"

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a very strange problem that I cannot get my head around.

I have a very simple table in a database that maps rows from one table to another. The purpose of this table is to change a many to many relationship to 2 1-to-many relationships.

I created this table in the edmx viewer in Entity Framework and Export it to SQlite via "Generate database from model" using the necessary .tt file.

Whenever I try to add a row to the table in the code I always get the error message:

"The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted."

The testing code I am using to add:

```
Dim PCMap As New PromProdBuyClauseMapping
PCMap.BuyClauseID = PromBC.ID
PCMap.ProductID = ProdIDs(RND.Next(0, ProdIDs.Count - 1)) ''Select rand prod
db.PromProdBuyClauseMapping.Add(PCMap)
db.SaveChanges()
```

All of the values seem OK. The rows are populated already in the necessary related tables. The error is thrown on db.savechanges. This used to work. I enabled FK support for SQLite and changed some code and it stopped working for some reason I am unsure of. I tried disabling FK support by changing the true to false in the connection string and strangely this did not work.

```
foreign keys=False
```

The SQLite for creating the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [PromProdBuyClauseMapping] (
[BuyClauseID] integer   NOT NULL ,
[ID] integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL ,
[ProductID] integer   NOT NULL 

,CONSTRAINT [FK_PromProdBuyClauseMappingPromBuyClause]
FOREIGN KEY ([BuyClauseID])
REFERENCES [PromBuyClause] ([ID])                   


,CONSTRAINT [FK_GeneralProductsPromProdBuyClauseMapping]
FOREIGN KEY ([ProductID])
REFERENCES [GeneralProducts] ([ID])                     
);
```

I have researched this problem a lot and I only found one other person who had the problem adding rows as opposed to deleting them and their issue did not seem similar enough to mine. I have also tried regenerating the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back and looked at the things I had changed. It turned out adding a property to one of the partial classes I had implemented that accessed the db itself was the issue. Changing this property to a function solved the issue. I am not entirely sure why this causes the issue. I have had other properties ion these partial classes although perhaps not trying to access the DB.